# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI + Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC but got an issue on my first application and I am not able to resolve it. I checked all articles available but still, I guess somewhere I am making some mistake.

Will you please able to help me to fix this?

**Web.xml**

```xml
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String goHome()
    {
        return "Welcome Home";
    }
}
```

is there something I am missing to configure? I know a very common issue but not getting the root cause.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen, Spring 4.3.14 and WebLogic

> **Error:**
>
> > atcherServlet:508 - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 791 ms 2018-02-24 12:37:22 WARN  PageNotFound:1176 - No
> >     mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc-project] in
> >     DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' <24 Feb, 2018, 12:37:28,882
> >     PM IST>      2018-02-24 12:37:28 WARN  PageNotFound:1176 -
> >     No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc-project/] in
> >     DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' <24 Feb, 2018, 12:37:38,883
> >     PM IST>      2018-02-24 12:43:12 WARN  PageNotFound:1176 -
> >     No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc-project/home]
> >     in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' <24 Feb, 2018,
> >     12:43:18,882 PM IST>

**dispatcher xml**

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springmvc.controller" />
```

Comment: It seems that you hit an incorrect URL in the browser.In your controller you don't have any mapping for /springmvc-project. Try to access /home instead trying to access /springmvc-project.

Comment: I tries but still no output (404 - not found) on the browser. Though I didn't get any error on the Console log. not getting what is wrong with it

Comment: show your `dispatcher-servelet.xml`, does it have `<context:component-scan>` attribute specify with value `base-package` to your controller package

Comment: @Shantaram Tupe yes I updated the question

Comment: where is your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`?

Comment: it's under /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml. I have added it in my question. Please refresh the page

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springmvc.controller" />

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking incorrect URL. You must not include your project name if not specified otherwise in your web.xml. So you should try hitting your server with something like this `http://localhost:8080/home`. Also you should specify type of request i.e. GET/POST in RequestMapping annotation.